# Webpack4 sass-loader fails with box-shadow

Tags: sass, webpack-4

using webpack4 with sass loader:

```
 {
  test: /.scss$/,
  exclude: [/node_modules/],
  use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader","sass-loader"]
 }
```

My build of this rule

```
div.leaflet-control-measure {
  border: 2px solid transparent !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgb(0,0,0,0.65) !important;
  > * {
    border: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
  }
}
```

fails with:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgb(0,0,0,0.65) !important;
                             ^
          Wrong number of arguments (4 for 3) for `rgb'
          in /Users/ts/Dropbox (Privat)/code/webpack4/src/main.scss (line 62, column 27)
```

What is wrong with the box-shadow? The number of arguments looks correct to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're using rgb (which takes 3 arguments) as if it was rgba (which takes 4).
You can either remove the fourth argument (the decimal) or change rgb for rgba.